# memory exception when execute cursor query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, cursor

In the following query cursor an exception **(An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.)**. I dont know why ? the number of records is : 3822

```
declare @ID int,
        @AccNo nvarchar(255),
        @Name nvarchar(255),
        @Type int, 
        @SubAcc bit,
        @Curr int,
        @dept nvarchar(255)
DECLARE cus CURSOR LOCAL FOR    
SELECT ID,
       AccNo,
       Name,
       Type,
       SubAcc,
       Curr,
       Department  
FROM chart_new   
order by ID

OPEN cus;
FETCH NEXT FROM cus INTO @ID,
                         @AccNo,
                         @Name,
                         @Type,
                         @SubAcc,
                         @Curr,
                         @dept
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0            
BEGIN               
   select @ID -- @ID--, COUNT (*) from FN_SPLIT_INT(@AccNo);
   FETCH NEXT FROM cus INTO @ID,
                            @AccNo,
                            @Name,
                            @Type,
                            @SubAcc,
                            @Curr,
                            @dept
END
CLOSE cus;  
DEALLOCATE cus;
```

Table Diff :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[chart_new](
    [ID] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AccNo] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Type] [int] NULL,
    [SubAcc] [bit] NULL,
    [Curr] [int] NULL,
    [Department] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [acclevel] [int] NULL,
    [haschild] [bit] NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [ClassID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_chart_new] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Add table definitions, incl. any index.

Comment: what mean `SLOW`?

Comment: @jarlh Q is ypdated

Comment: takes more than 1 min

Comment: Cursors will always be slow compared to set-based operations. Also, it looks like this is the result of some very poor schema design, where multiple Account Numbers live as delimited values in the same column. **NEVER** store delimited values in a single column. Finally.. that exception is a .Net error. It's _not thrown by your database,_ but by the client program the uses the database.

Comment: The only think I can see is the `order by`  that is the most cost process if you dont have index for that column. Try to do the cursor without order

Comment: it is generate memory exception